# Hive derby/mysql installation

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 2 queries from the below logs:

1. How to get rid of the first line WARN message.
2. Why is Hive complaining about the xml as its correctly formatted or am i missing something.

   ```
   15/04/23 18:26:58 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.local does not exist

   Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:472)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:671)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
   at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:515)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:458)
   ... 7 more
   **Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D**
   at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
   at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:203)
   ... 10 more
   ```

kindly suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is Hadoop "Path" doesn't support ':' in filenames.

So, replace ${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name} by /tmp/mydir in hive-site.xml

Referenced from this link

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration.

Comment: The next error i get it "java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bhive.session.id%7D_resources" what should i replace it with?      I replaced it with /usr/local/hive_workspace that should be fine?

Comment: I hope you have replaced all such occurences as mentioned above in hive-site.xml. If still the issue persists, pls share your hive-site.xml here.

By all I mean <name>hive.querylog.location</name> 
<name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
<name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue.@partha is right. The issue is Hadoop "Path" doesn't support ':' in filenames.

So i modified the hive-site.xml with following properties and it worked.

```
<name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
<value>/tmp/hive-${user.name}</value>

 <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
 <value>/tmp/${user.name}</value>

<name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
<value>/tmp/${user.name}_resources</value>
```

Comment: thanks @sunanda, it helps me, i were struggling with this subjected thread issue...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first line WARN message, 
the warning tells you that the hive.metastore.local key is not used. Try to remove this configuration from your hive-site.xml, if you are more concerned about removing the warning